# Get timestamp from date & time in UTC

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table that have date and time with timezone.

```
date_time_table
+------------+--------------+
|   date_t   |   time_tz    |
+------------+--------------+
| 2016-05-13 | 23:00:00 -02 |
| 2016-05-14 | 13:00:00 +06 |
+------------+--------------+
```

After that I run SQL for query 'UTC' time

```
SELECT timetz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM date_time_tz
```

The result is:

```
+--------------+
|   time_tz    |
+--------------+
| 01:00:00 +00 |
| 07:00:00 +00 |
+--------------+
```

Can I write SQL combined date_t with time_tz for calculate with date too?

The result that I expect is:

```
+------------+------------+
|      date_time_tz       |
+------------+------------+
| 2016-05-14 01:00:00 +00 |
| 2016-05-14 07:00:00 +00 |
+------------+------------+
```

I try with :

```
SELECT concat(date_t , ' ' ,time_tz) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM date_time_table
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Why don't use a `timestamp` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT concat(date_t , ' ' ,time_tz)::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM date_time_table
```

Try casting like this

Comment: Thank for knowledge about casting now I solve problem by 
**SELECT concat(date_t , ' ' ,time_tz)::timestamp WITH TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM date_time_table**

Answer (score 2):

If the columns are of `date` and `time` types:

```
select (current_date + current_time) at time zone 'UTC';
          timezone          
----------------------------
 2016-07-12 12:06:00.239396
```

If those columns are text:

```
select ('2016-01-01'::date + '23:00:00 -02'::timetz) at time zone 'UTC';
      timezone       
---------------------
 2016-01-02 01:00:00
```